# List with square bracket and no brackets in Python

Tags: python, list, square-bracket

I want to know whether both of these are a list or not. In python, are both of these lists?

```
x = [1,2,3]
## and
y = 1,2,3
```

Is `y` a list?

Comment: You can get an idea by using `type(y)`

Answer (score 6):

`x` is a list, but `y` is a [*tuple*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange). The [parentheses to define a tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists) are optional in most contexts; it is the *comma* that defines the value, really.

You can test this yourself with the [`type()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type):

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> type(x)
<type 'list'>
>>> y = 1,2,3
>>> type(y)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> y
(1, 2, 3)
```

Tuples are immutable; you can create one but then not alter the contents (add, remove or replace elements).

Answer (score 4):

No.  The first is a list and the second is a tuple:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> type(x)
<class 'list'>
>>> y = 1,2,3  # This is equivalent to doing:  y = (1,2,3)
>>> type(y)
<class 'tuple'>
>>>
```

As a note for the future, if you ever want to see the type of an object, you can use the [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) built-in as I demonstrated above.